# JavaScript issue with import/export modules and Globally defined variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

(note, I'm using Node.js to create a telnet server and handle user input)
I'm having issues using variables/arrays in javascript inside functions in other scripts.

Let me set a simpler example:

```
var connections = []
```

is an array in my main.js
Broadcast.js is a function I put in a separate module and attempt to use the broadcast() function in my main.js.

The error I get is stating that connections is undefined.  How do get Broadcast.js able to see the connections array in the main.js
~~

For example in my main.js I set an array to handle clients connecting to a server

```
//point to Telnet library
const Telnet = require('ranvier-telnet');
const logger = require('./logger.js')
var outspeak = []
var connections = []
var clients = []






let server = new Telnet.TelnetServer(rawSocket => {

let telnetSocket = new Telnet.TelnetSocket();
//attaching socket
telnetSocket.attach(rawSocket);
//setting telnet options
telnetSocket.telnetCommand(Telnet.Sequences.WILL, Telnet.Options.OPT_EOR);
//giving clients a name
telnetSocket.name = rawSocket.remoteAddress + ":" + rawSocket.remotePort
//pushing client names to array
clients.push(telnetSocket.name);
//pushing client connections to an array
connections.push(rawSocket);
console.log(`${telnetSocket.name} has connected`)
logger(`${telnetSocket.name} has connected`)
broadcast(telnetSocket.name + " connected.")


telnetSocket.on('data', function (data) {
    //broadcast (telnetSocket.name + ">" + data, telnetSocket);
}

function broadcast (message, sender) {
    connections.forEach(function (connection) {
        //don't want to send it to sender
        if (connection === sender) return;
    connection.write(`${message} \n`);
    });

}
```

Now inside my main script, I could called that array/push to that array, read from that array, as long as I type out the function inside the main.js file.

And it can easily use the broadcast function.

Now I want to make it more advance and make reduce my lines on my main.js

but once I separate the broadcast function into it's own module.

```
use strict'
//broadcast function

    function broadcast (message, sender) {
        connections.forEach(function (connection) {
            //don't want to send it to sender
            if (connection === sender) return;
        connection.write(`${message} \n`);
        });

    }

module.exports = broadcast
```

I get a connection undefined error any time I try to invoke that broadcast function.  It's like my global variable/array can't be seen by broadcast.js function.

this is how I'm invoking it

```
    // handle input
    telnetSocket.on('data', function (data) {
    broadcast (telnetSocket.name + ">" + data, telnetSocket);
    });
```

And yes, const broadcast = require('./broadcast.js'); as been added to the file at the top.

Here's the broken code complete:

```
'use strict'
//point to Telnet library
const Telnet = require('ranvier-telnet');
const logger = require('./logger.js');
const broadcast = require('./broadcast.js');
var connections = []
var clients = []




//had to call message as global variable


//Asan's timestamp functionm
//telnetstuff


console.log("Starting..."); 





let server = new Telnet.TelnetServer(rawSocket => {

    let telnetSocket = new Telnet.TelnetSocket();
    //attaching socket
    telnetSocket.attach(rawSocket);
    //setting telnet options
    telnetSocket.telnetCommand(Telnet.Sequences.WILL, Telnet.Options.OPT_EOR);
    //giving clients a name
    telnetSocket.name = rawSocket.remoteAddress + ":" + rawSocket.remotePort
    //pushing client names to array
    clients.push(telnetSocket.name);
    //pushing client connections to an array
    connections.push(rawSocket);
    console.log(`${telnetSocket.name} has connected`)
    logger(`${telnetSocket.name} has connected`)
    broadcast(telnetSocket.name + " connected.")


    // handle input
    telnetSocket.on('data', function (data) {
    broadcast (telnetSocket.name + ">" + data, telnetSocket);
    });

//removing client/connection from array
rawSocket.on('end', function () {
        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(telnetSocket), 1);
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(rawSocket), 1);
        broadcast(telnetSocket.name + " has left.\n");
        logger(telnetSocket.name + " has left.");
        console.log(telnetSocket.name + " has left.");
    });


}).netServer


server.listen(4000);

console.log('ServerRunning...');
logger('>Server started.');
```

What I'm missing here?  Also I apologize in advance this is my first question ever asked and I've gone through as much I could today to even figure out how to ask my question, maybe I'm not using correct lingo/terms? any help is appreciative.

```
refactor\broadcast.js:5
                connections.forEach(function (connection) {
                ^

ReferenceError: connections is not defined
```

Comment: This code is from broadcast.js ??

Comment: Some code maybe missing where us the loop of `connections.forEach(function (connection)`

Comment: rawSocket where is initialized ?

Comment: main.js is the telnet script.  rawSocket is from the ranvier-telnet library, handles all the sockets and stuff and all main.js is booting up the server and handling client connections.

Comment: broadcast.js is just this function                                                                                                     function broadcast (message, sender) {
  connections.forEach(function (connection) {
   //don't want to send it to sender
   if (connection === sender) return;
  connection.write(`${message} \n`);
  });
  
 }

Comment: I wanted to separated that function into it's own module, but it won't work.  If it's too unreadable I can haste bin it all together and may make more sense.

Comment: https://hastebin.com/salahiloye.js is my main "loop", and I wanna use this https://hastebin.com/avigijudag.js inside of it.

Comment: and to note, this works if it's all in the same script (working code: https://hastebin.com/zanifedeyu.js )

Comment: Why you are using Telnet server and not Express server ???

Comment: I'm making a MUD.

Answer (score 0):

In nodejs, when you declare a variable not inside any function definitions, it is scoped to the file only. (This is different from browser javascript.) If you want something to be accessible from outside, you need to export it:

```
module.exports.connections = connections;
```

Then import it into the other file:

```
const connections = require(myFile);
```

This will work as long as you don't try to set the value of the variable in either file, but if you do that they'll end up pointing to separate objects. But mutating it, calling methods on it, etc should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, that gave me a new error.  Now my .forEach doesn't work in separating connections into individual connection.  I might have to think of a completely different way to do what I'm trying to achieve. (which is just write to all sockets or specific sockets in the array).

Comment: connections.forEach(function (connection) {
                            ^

TypeError: connections.forEach is not a function
    at broadcast (C:\Users\Luke\Coding stuff\Portum\refactor\broadcast.js:5:15)

Comment: Did you export `connections` before or after you set it to `[]`?

Comment: I did it after.

Comment: Could there be a circular dependency involving these two files?

Comment: Maybe, I'll be honest as I'm very new to programming.  So that's sort what I guess I was trying to do.  there's no way to write to all sockets with out the current connected sockets being in an array, but I don't know how to push that data to another file to be use in it's function.  And then return the output of that function back to the main file loop.